# datepicker, after second call no correct display

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

the jQuery calendar is placed at the second call "false" represents!
That is click the user in the first "Von" (from) field, the calendar is called correctly.
If the user clicks in the "Bis" (to) field, the calendar is called correctly.
But the user clicks resist the "Von" (from) field on the calendar is called incorrectly, the user can scroll through the "future" of the Calendar is called without restriction!

Here the integration of the source code:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $( "#date_Von" ).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 3,
                        dayNamesMin: [ "So","Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ],
                        monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez" ],
                        monthNames: ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
                        maxDate: "+0d",
                        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
                        prevText: "Zurück",
                        nextText: "Weiter",
                        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                            $( "#date_Bis" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate ); 
                        }
                    });
                    $( "#date_Bis" ).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 3,
                        dayNamesMin: [ "So","Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ],
                        monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez" ],
                        monthNames: ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
                        maxDate: "+0d",
                        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1), 
                        prevText: "Zurück",
                        nextText: "Weiter",
                        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                            $( "#date_Von" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
   </script>
```

first call: [image]

After the second click in the "Von" (From) field:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: You don't need `$(function() {` two times ... just remove extra one.

Comment: I have removed the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you close the second datepicker without selecting a date, the maxDate is set as blank, effectively removing the validation from field one.

So 1 possible solution is to use the onSelect event

```
$(function () {
    $("#date_Von").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        maxDate: "+0d",
        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
        prevText: "Zurück",
        nextText: "Weiter",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#date_Bis").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#date_Bis").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        maxDate: "+0d",
        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
        prevText: "Zurück",
        nextText: "Weiter",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#date_Von").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

---

If you want to use the close handler itself then if the date is blank then set the default constraint value

```
$(function () {
    $("#date_Von").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        maxDate: "+0d",
        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
        prevText: "Zurück",
        nextText: "Weiter",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#date_Bis").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate || new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1));
        }
    });
    $("#date_Bis").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"],
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
        maxDate: "+0d",
        minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1),
        prevText: "Zurück",
        nextText: "Weiter",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#date_Von").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate || '+0d');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y1y61Lzm/2/ & http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y1y61Lzm/3/

Comment: Thank You.
That with `onSelect` is in my case enough, it is the solution.